# jQuery grid recommendations for large data sets?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, grid, large-data-volumes

I was looking around for jQuery grid recommendations and came across this question/answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

In looking through the many jQuery grid solutions out there, it seems they all want to have the entire data set on the client.  If I have a large data set (thousands/millions of records), these types of solutions will obviously not scale well (or work at all)

My question: are there jQuery grid solution out there that use Ajax to select just a page at a time?  I expect to handle the paging, sorting, etc on the server side with the arguments passed in from the client via ajax.

Thanks in advance,

--Ed

Update: I am using FlexiGrid with great success - the rest of the app is ASP.NET MVC2.  The only gotcha is you need to modify the Site.css that comes with ASP.NET MVC as it specifies a style for all tables, td, and th tags (padding) that messes up the flexigrid L&F.

Update 2: over at fishysplash, there is a nice implementation of a dynamic generation of the necessary javascript code if you're planning to have more than one grid with different data tables.
http://fishysplash.com/adding-grids-using-flexigrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Elijah Manor did something with this using the FlexGrid and ASP.NET MVC: http://webdevdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/07/flexigrid.html.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with : https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid
Here are some nice examples : https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples